# How can I create PDF using R when a lot of control is needed in tables and plots

Tags: r, pdf, graph

I'm converting several SAS programs to **R**. Reading, data wrangling, and stats are straight forward enough. I'm at a point where I need to create the PDF. I need a lot of control over the format of the PDF and objects in the PDF (e.g. margins, fonts, tables (column widths, cell padding, border widths, cell background color, and alternating table row colors), plots (width, height, position on the page) and line spacing). I've converted a PDF page created from the SAS program to JPG:

[image]

In SAS, this is done using various options and procedures (proc gplot, proc report, ods text, and proc template). Can someone point me to the best approach for creating this type of PDF output using **R**?

Comment: You can create the document using [`rmarkdown` to write the report](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) (including any R code needed to generate the tables graphs and calculated values). Then choose  [PDF as the output format](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/pdf_document_format.html). Generating tables with fill colors is probably most easily done with the [`kableExtra` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/index.html) (which adds additional functionality to the `kable` function (which generates basic tables and is found in the `knitr` package)).

Comment: I haven't tried to create layouts as complex as what you describe. It's certainly possible, but you may need to add some `latex` markup to the document to get exactly what you want, as I'm not sure everything you want can be done using just `rmarkdown`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments eipi10. I've been playing around with LaTex and think that will give me the functionality I need. I'm surprised they marked this as off-topic. Most answers on StackOverflow are based on someone's opinion as to the best approach/answer. At any rate, I love this forum - it's one of my first go-to resources when I get stumped.

Comment: I think that probably happened because your question was "Can someone point me to the best approach..." which is a bit vague and also because you didn't provide any sample data for people to use as grist for the coding mill. I suggest you edit your question to ask a couple of specific things like "how can I create a PDF document so as to include (1) a table with conditional background coloring and (2) both two-column and single-column layouts on the same page?" Ideally, you would also provide some sample data and any code you've already tried.

Comment: If you edit the question as suggested above, there's a good chance it will be reopened.